# how to solve 3x+1 on python

Tags: python, math, collatz

```py
    from random import randrange

    a = randrange(1, 9)
    print (a)

    if (a % 2) == 0:         
        y = a / 2        
    while True:     
        if (y % 2) == 0:      
            y = y / 2
            print (y)
        else: 
            b = (a * 3) + 1
    while True: 
        if (b % 2) == 0:
            b = b / 2
        else: 
            b = (a * 3) + 1   
        print (b)
```

"I want to make a math problem solver in python that can find a random number

between 1 and 9. Then if it is odd so it multiply it with 3 and add 1 in it and if it

is even so it divide it by two and this process keep repeating. For example a number

computer choose is 7 so :
`7*3 + 1 = 22`
`22/2 = 11`
`11*3 = 33`
and so on.
It shouldn't stop until the answer is 0.Here is my code in which I tried but not sure where should I make it right?"

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the post, and remove the double spacing.

Comment: How will it *ever* reach zero?

Comment: Are you sure you have the problem correct? The [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is that it always reaches 1, not 0.

Comment: You have no `break` statements, so `while True:` is an infinite loop.

Comment: yes it will never reach 0 so I want to run it forever. However, let's say I wanna stop it on 1 so what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You have too many lines in there.  You need to loop to stop repeating when the number becomes 1 (it will never become 0):

```
from random import randrange

a = randrange(1, 9)

while a != 1:
    print(a)
    if a % 2 == 0:
        a = a // 2
    else:
        a = (a * 3) + 1

print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. Appreciated.

Comment: @Esbah you should accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check for any number or any range of numbers. This code is created by using the recursive function approach.

```
def f(x): #creating a function
  if x!=4:
    a.append(x)
    if x%2==0:
      while x%2==0:
        x=x/2
        a.append(x)
    x=3*x+1
    f(x)
```

For checking a particular value, run this:

```
a=[]
f(2**100+1) #2 to the power 10, plus 1
a[-1]
```

For checking for a range of values, run this:

```
for i in range(1,100):
  a=[]
  f(i)
  print(i, "gives output" ,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I call it impossible maths because never reaches zero, it just keeps on looping forever [Collatz problem](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lagarias/#:%7E:text=The%203x%2B1%20problem%2C%20also,integers%20n%20to%20n%2F2.). But this function does that, it does not take any parameter.

```
import random as r

def impossible_math():
  x = r.ran(1,9)
  while x !=0:
   if x%2 ==0:
    x = x/2
    print(x)
   else:
    x = (x*3)+1
    print(x)

x = impossible_math()
```